# rosmake { rosjava, rosjava_core } fails

Tags: rosmake, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, both `rosmake rosjava` and `rosmake rosjava_core` fail with the following error (on Env-1):

```
  rosrun rosjava_bootstrap make.py apache_commons_util
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/rosman/ros_ws/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 108, in <module>
      main(sys.argv)
    File "/home/rosman/ros_ws/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 100, in main
      build(rospack, package)
    File "/home/rosman/ros_ws/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 59, in build
      maven_depmap = maven.get_maven_dependencies(package, 'dependencies.xml')
    File "/home/rosman/ros_ws/rosjava/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/maven.py", line 216, in get_maven_dependencies
      subprocess.check_call(command)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 499, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 486, in call
      return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
      errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1213, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Error on Env-2 is similar.

I checked files/folders (`rosjava_bootstrap make.py apache_commons_util`) that are called by `rosrun` in the error are all found.

Also I'm confused if I should download and use `rosjava` or `rosjava_core`. [This page](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout) says I should use

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/
```

but [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/2472/rosjava-missing-library) says

```
hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ rosjava_core
```

**Env-1**: Ubuntu 11.04, electric, python2.7

**Env-2**: Ubuntu 10.10, electric, python2.6

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11599/rosmake-%7B-rosjava,-rosjava_core-%7D-fails/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error that is being raised would usually be caused if you don't have ant installed.  Ant is a build tool for java.

As for the hg clone instructions, Google Code auto-generates checkout documentation.  The correct instructions are:

hg clone https://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/ rosjava_core

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-19**:
Thanks, those solved my problem and now rosmake completes w/o errors (after ant, I still had to install javac via openjdk-6-jdk though).